# Filter and sort alternativ paths in a graph based environment

Tags: lambda, c++17, variadic-templates

Since I don't know how to ask the question directly, I'd like to introduce the problem step by step:

Imagine a vector of (wrapping) objects and you need to sort and filter.
Normally, I'd do something like this:

```cpp
class Foo
{
   Bar* bar
   int CalcDistance();            // operates on bar;
   std::vector<int> GetObjects(); // operates on bar;
};

std::vector<Foo*> process()
{
  std::vector<Foo*> foos = GetFoosFromSomewhere();
  std::vector<Foo*> potentialFoos;

  auto the_filter = [&](auto foo){ 
    return foo->CalcDistance() < MAGIC_NUMBER && !foo->GetObjects().empty(); 
  };
  std::copy_if(foos.begin(), foos.end(), potentialFoos.begin(), the_filter);

  auto the_sorter = [&](auto lhs, auto rhs){ return lhs->CalcDistance() > rhs->CalcDistance(); };
  std::sort(potentialFoos.begin(), potentialFoos.end(), the_sorter);

  return potentialFoos;
}
```

Unfortunatly, I don't need to filter a vector of Foos. Instead, the individual queries operate on a graph and return multiple results when given a target (vertex in the graph).

If there are three possiblities to get to the target, you get three distances and three vectors of objects, respectively.

```cpp
class Foo
{
   Bar* bar
   std::vector<int> CalcDistance(Vertex target);            // operates on bar, based on a graph;
   std::vector<std::vector<int>> GetObjects(Vertex target); // operates on bar, based on a graph;
};
```

I'd like to have an easy (expressive) way to sort and filter alternative paths, leading to the same target. What I can imagine is something like this:

```cpp
// pseudo-code
Foo foo = GetFooFromSomewhere();
std::vector<Vertex> targets = GetTargetsFromSomewhere();

auto the_filter = [](Distance d, Objects o){ return d < MAGIC_NUMBER && !o.empty() };
auto the_sorter = [](Distances d){ return d.lhs < d.rhs; }
auto alternatives = SortAndFilter(foo, targets, 
  filter<Distance, Objects>(the_filter), 
  sorter<Distance>(the_sorter));
```

I've already made some progress using variadic templates and fold expressions to decompose the individual Query objects (here Distance and Objects) of the lambdas (see http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a095f1adcf61de4), but it's (a) not complete, (b) not as expressive as I'd like to have it and (c) certainly the "reinvention of the year".

The ultimate goal is to hide the complexity of the underlying method calls to the wrapped bar object from the end user with being able to extend the queries e.g. by template specialization.

The problem is my feeling about reinventing the wheel and I'm pretty sure, that there are some better ways to do that (e.g. some nice stuff on top of boost graph).

Any ideas (improvements)?

Comment: `std::copy_if(foos.begin(), foos.end(), potentialFoos.begin(), the_filter);` exhibits undefined behavior, by way of writing beyond the container's bounds. `potentialFoos` is an empty vector. Well, except if `the_filter` always returns `false`

Comment: Thanks Igor for the comment. Luckily, this is not real code (was written out of my head) - just learned: never make shortcuts in C++ ;)